# How to create a dynamic array of strings as the array is a member of a struct in C++?

Tags: c++, string, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
struct vehicle {
int len = 0 ;
int *id = new int[len] , *price = new int[len] ;
string *model = new string[len] , *brand = new string[len] ;
};


void insert(vehicle& v) {
cout << "Enter id\n" ;
cin >> v.id[v.len] ;
cout << "Enter brand, model, and price\n" ;

cin >> v.brand[v.len] >>  v.model[v.len] >> v.price[v.len] ;
v.len++ ;
}

int main() {
vehicle v ;
insert(v) ;
cout << v.id[0] ;
delete v.id , v.brand , v.model , v.price ;
}
```

It always gives a wrong termination how can I fix that ??
(additional question) is the last line necessary or not ??(the delete statement).

Comment: Everything about this code is just plain wrong. The use of `new[]` and `delete` are wrong. The `insert()` method is coded wrong. Dynamic arrays can't grow like you are attempting. You have to allocate a new array each time. Make things easier on yourself and just use `std::vector` instead, let it do all of the array management for you.

Comment: You are writing past the end of your arrays.  You allocate them of zero length and never grow them.

Answer (score 3):

`len` inside `Vehicle` is always `0` when the `int` arrays are created. C++ arrays don't work like python arrays and can't just be resized. If you want this kind of appending functionality, you should be using a `std::vector`.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// using namespace std; Don't do this.

struct vehicle {
    std::vector<int> id, price;
    std::vector<std::string> model, brand;
};

void insert(vehicle& v) {
    int id, price;
    std::string brand, model;
    std::cout << "Enter id\n" ;
    std::cin >> id;
    std::cout << "Enter brand, model, and price\n" ;
    std::cin >> brand >> model >> price;
    v.id.push_back(id);
    v.price.push_back(price);
    v.brand.push_back(std::move(brand));
    v.model.push_back(std::move(model));
}
```

This would all be much simpler if you used a vector of structs instead of a struct of vectors:

```cpp
struct vehicle {
    int id, price;
    std::string brand, model;
};

vehicle get_vehicle() {
    vehicle v;
    std::cout << "Enter id\n" ;
    std::cin >> v.id;
    std::cout << "Enter brand, model, and price\n" ;
    std::cin >> v.brand >> v.model >> v.price;
    return v;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<vehicle> vehicles;
    vehicles.push_back(get_vehicle());
}
```